# How to get multiple random documents from angularfire firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I've been looking for solutions but non worked for my application, I'm trying to build a Quiz app using angular and firestore with angularfire, my current approach:

```
public getRandomQuestion(): Promise<any> {
    let ques: IQuestion;
    return this.firestore.collection('questions', ref => ref.where('randId', '>=', this.getRandomInt(1,999999)).limit(1)).valueChanges().toPromise();
  }
  public getTenRandomQuestion(): IQuestion[]{
    let obs : IQuestion[] = [];
    for (let i: number = 0; i <= 9; i++){
      this.getRandomQuestion().then(res => {
        obs[i] = res;
      });
    }
    console.log(obs);
    return obs;
}
```

But it always returns an empty array, here's my firestore :
[Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ob4u8.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you add some logging or run the code in a debugger, you can most easily see that your `return obs` runs before the `obs[i] = res` is ever called.

So that explains why you always get an empty array, your `getTenRandomQuestion` method ends before any data has been loaded from the database.

The solution is to return a `Promise`, just like you do from `getRandomQuestion`.

```
  public getTenRandomQuestion(): Promise<IQuestion>[]{
    let obs : Promise<IQuestion>[] = [];
    for (let i: number = 0; i <= 9; i++){
      obs[i] = this.getRandomQuestion();
    }
    return obs;
  }
```

And then when you call `getTenRandomQuestion`, you either add a `then()` clause, or you [use `async` and `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Comment: It didnt seem to work for me? Can you point out whats wrong?
https://imgur.com/a/CuDOoVk